# Import python modules from the same directory as the script running

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, python-module

I have a task from school to make a simple adventure game in python. In order for the teachers to see my program, I have to run my python script on the school computers. I want to use pygame in my program. The problem is that student accounts have very limited access. We cannot modify local directories, environment paths or run .exe files. This is a problem because I cannot install the pygame module on the computer. My only choice is to somehow include pygame in the same directory as the main python script that will be run.

Is there a way to use the pygame modules without using pip or easy_install and just include pygame in the same directory as the game itself?

Comment: You can just download the source and include / use it.

Comment: You should ask your teacher; if they assigned making a game, they must have some way for you to use libraries

Comment: Actually - if you have pygame in current directory it should get easily imported. What you can do is - copy the package to some directory (say your home directory) and add that to sys.path .

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the teacher to give you permission to run .exe (maybe they can enter administrator password for you at runtime?), you could create a .exe with PyInstaller (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36456473/6167592) with your game. It bundles all the libraries and depedencies into the .exe, so you don't need to install Python on the school computer. Also have your .py files handy to show your code to the teacher. Note that you need Python to use PyInstaller, so you won't be able to change your code and remake a .exe once at school.