# I want to make .py file into exe file by using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, anaconda, pyinstaller

I'm making a program by using pygame and want to make it into executable file.
The program will run correctly if it is python script.
 
But there was a problem, if I treid to make it as executable file.
I made a spec file shown below  and ran it to bundle all dependencies into executable file.
Finally, I could made executable file however it failed runnning with showing error messages as below.

↓error messages I got(it says there is no folder named "resources"! but I did make virtual folder.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Renmu.jpg

How can I fix this problem?

(I referenced this document https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html)

PyInstaller version: 3.3.1
Python version: 3.6.6

↓my python script

```
#pygame_test.py located at Desktop/RPG_test
import pygame,sys,os
print(os.getcwd())
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image_path,root):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centerx = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
        self.rect.centery = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

def main():
    pygame.init()
    root = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
    running = True
    player = Player("resources/tiger_window.png",root)
    group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    group.add(player)
    fps = 30
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while running:
        clock.tick(fps)
        root.fill((50,150,200))
        group.update()
        group.draw(root)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.event.clear()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

↓spec file which I made by "pyi-makespec" command.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['pygame_test.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\Ayata\\Desktop\\RPG_test'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[("C:/Users/Ayata/Desktop/RPG_test/resources/tiger_window.png","resources")],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='pygame_test',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```

Comment: instead of using absolute path use relative path

Comment: What should I do is changing "resources/tiger_window.png" to "C:/Users/Ayata/Desktop/RPG_test/resources/tiger_window.png"?

Comment: I want to distribute exe file for my friends. I think

Comment: I think the solution you suggested will only work on my environment...

Comment: i am sayiing use os.getpwd() to get current path and use that way to get path in system , and change  `C:/Users/Ayata/Desktop/RPG_test/resources/tiger_window.png` to  `resources/tiger_window.png`  to

Comment: Ok! I'll try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first things that happens after you run a PyInstaller-built single-file executable is that [a temporary directory is created](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works). The executable then unpacks a bunch of resource files into this directory, as well as the custom data files (like your `tiger_window.png` file). In your scripts you can retrieve the path to this directory from variable `sys._MEIPASS`.

The following snippet of code should provide the correct path to the image file in both  'development' mode and in 'frozen' mode:

```
try:
    # Get temporary directory created by PyInstaller single-file executable
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except AttributeError:
    # Get directory in which this script file resides
    base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Get path to image file
img_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'resources/tiger_window.png')
```

### Alternative solution

You could also let PyInstaller [freeze your script into a directory (with multiple files) instead of just one single executable](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/operating-mode.html#what-pyinstaller-does-and-how-it-does-it). If you do this no modifications to your script file should be necessary. An added benefit is that start-up time for your game will likely be shorter (because no unpacking of files is needed).

Comment: Your answer was  very useful for me! 
I finally suceeded making one single executable and it works fine everywhere!
I'll keep in mind that "sys._MEIPASS" is very very important!
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

this answer by @Bobsleigh helped
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36456473

you basically need to add data to a .spec file and run "pyinstaller my_spec_file" (assuming you want one directory bundle not one file exe, for the difference between the two visit pyinstaller docs)