# I am facing a cmd error while converting .py to .exe

Tags: pygame

So recently i made a pygame that i want to share with my friends but i find it difficult to run the exe file of it i converted the py to a exe file using pyinstaller but whenever i try running the .exe file a cmd screen shows up and it just closes my game does not run whatsoever it works fine in pygame. I dont have any erros being displayed yet just a black cmd file comes up when clicked and just closes. This is my pygame project that i need to show next week so please can someone help me out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For pygame applications you should rather use the **py2exe** module instead of **pyinstalle**r.

Using pyinstaller will not work unless you create a spec file to let it know how to package the resources. In order to create a spec file, you have to simply run pyinstaller.
You can follow the instructions in this answer:
[Pyinstaller with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033003/pyinstaller-with-pygame)