# How to fix "WARNING: Hidden import "pygame._view" not found!" when converting .py to .exe using PyInstaller?

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

This is the MRE of my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen.fill((255, 215, 0))

x_coordinate = 330
y_coordinate = 250
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, False, False)
writing = font.render("this is a test", 1, (0,0,0))


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            screen.blit(writing,(x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Now, when I run this using cmd or IDLE, it runs perfectly. But when I make its executable (the command I used was "pyinstaller --onefile {name of python file}") using pyinstaller, there appears a warning on the cmd window: "WARNING: Hidden import "pygame._view" not found!" I thought that pygame._view is a different module than pygame, so I added `import pygame._view` to no avail (I also tried to install it using pip, but no module exists by that name).

Now, when I run the executable created, I get an error message which says, "test.exe has stopped working".

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Try using cx_freeze to create your exe.

Comment: the pygame._view is not causing the problem. it's more that pygame is using ressources that are not embedded in your exe. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033003/pyinstaller-with-pygame for more details. In your case I managed to have the exe run removing related to font (and writing). So have a close look to the comments in the link I provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace "comicsans" with "comicsansms". For some reasons pygame.Fonts is handling the situation, ie comicsans not being a System Font, when run as a py file but not within the exe