# pyinstaller --onefile argument doesn't work with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I have a pathfinding maze program that uses the Pygame module, and for whatever reason whenever I run the pyinstaller `--onefile` argument, I get `Failed to execute script main`. I moved all my assets over to the new folder so it's not that. I also don't have any fonts in my code.

Exact command I'm running: `pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole`
If I run it withouth the `--onefile`, it works perfectly.

Comment: If you remove the `--noconsole` but keep `--onefile` and run the executable via the command line, do you get any useful output?

Comment: It gives me an error: `No such file or directory.`. Strange it only says that if I don't include `--noconsole`

Comment: Do you have any path references in your files?  Those tend to break when using --onefile

Comment: Yes actually, I'll try removing them.

Comment: Thank you that worked

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36456473/2280890) for details on how to properly include files and reference them in your code.